# How would I create my own .hide() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would a basic function look like that I can attach to (and manipulate) a selected element?

E.g. to show a hidden element:

```
mySelectedElement.hideElement();
```

Trying the above with the following code gives this error:

> TypeError: $(...).hideElement is not a function

```
function hideElement() {
  this.css({
      display: none
    });
  return this;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a 'hide' function?

Comment: @TilakMadichetti There are naive questions, tedious questions, ill-phrased questions, questions put after inadequate self-criticism. But every question is a cry to understand the world. There is no such thing as a dumb question.

Comment: I agree bro !! @Fellow just voted:) !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this : You need to define function in jquery way, see below function

If defining function inside js file-

```
$.fn.hideElement= function() {
    $(this).css({
      display: 'none'
    });
};
```

If defining function inside `$(document).ready(..` -

```
var hideElement = function() {
    $(this).css({
      display: 'none'
    });
};
```

Comment: Hm, the first function returns this error: "ReferenceError: none is not defined"

Comment: Put `none` in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

A syntax for creating a jQuery plugin

```
(function($){
    $.fn.<yourfn> = function(opt){
        //Take care of jQuery chaining by return this
        //Take care of multiple selections say $('div, span, p').<yourfn>() using .each
        return this.each(
            function(){
                /* your TODO goes here */
            };
        ); 
    }; 
})(jQuery);
```

So your hideElement function should be like

```
(function($){
    $.fn.showElement = function(options){
        return this.each(
            function(){
                $(this).css({display: none});
            };
        ); 
    }; 
})(jQuery);
```

Call `$('div,p').hideElement();`